# Facebook Send Dialog: An error occurred. Please try again later

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am trying to use the FB Send Dialog API. It works fine for most users except for one particular user.

```
  FB.init({appId: fbappid, xfbml: true, cookie: true});
 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') { 
     FB.ui({
      method: 'send',
  to: 'username',
  display: 'iframe',
      name: 'I just suggested a time and place',
      link: linkval,
  picture: 'http://'+domain+'/img/cupicon.png',
  access_token: response.authResponse.accessToken     // **This should work and tested** also!!!
      })

          };
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was that I was getting the following error: Object {error_code: 100, error_msg: "Viewer+cannot+message+specified+recipients."}

This is a permissions issue based on what that given user has setup.